# Joy to control servo

Tags: ros, arduino, joy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm using Hydro.

I've been working on and off with this code to control a servo using rosserial with an Arduino, using a PS3 controller and the Joy node.

I wrote my code based off of [this](http://wiki.ros.org/joy/Tutorials/WritingTeleopNode) tutorial. Here is my code

```
 #include <ros/ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/UInt16.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/Joy.h>


class Servo
{
public:
  Servo();

private:
  void joyCallback(const sensor_msgs::Joy::ConstPtr& joy);
  
  ros::NodeHandle nh_;

 // Joystick tuning params
  int linear_, angular_;
  double l_scale_, a_scale_;
  
  // Joystick dev to listen to
  ros::Subscriber joy_sub;

  // Robot bits to control
  ros::ServiceClient create_client;
  ros::ServiceClient servo_client;

  ros::Publisher deg_pub_;  // I want to publish an angle as std_msgs/UInt16
  ros::Subscriber joy_sub_;
};


Servo::Servo():  
  linear_(1),
  angular_(2)
{

  nh_.param("axis_linear", linear_, linear_);
  nh_.param("axis_angular", angular_, angular_);
  nh_.param("scale_angular", a_scale_, a_scale_);
  nh_.param("scale_linear", l_scale_, l_scale_);


  deg_pub_ = nh_.advertise<std_msgs::UInt16>("servo", 1);


  joy_sub_ = nh_.subscribe<sensor_msgs::Joy>("joy", 10, &Servo::joyCallback, this);

}  

void Servo::joyCallback(const sensor_msgs::Joy::ConstPtr& joy)
{
  std_msgs::UInt16 deg; 
  deg = l_scale_*joy->axes[linear_];
  deg_pub_.publish(deg);
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "servo_joy");
  Servo servo_joy;

  ros::spin();
}
```

I get some errors when I try to build it.

One is

```
/home/donni/catkin_ws/src/rosberry_pichoptor/src/servo.cpp:55:35: error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘deg = (((Servo*)this)->Servo::l_scale_ * ((double)(& joy)->boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator-> [with T = const sensor_msgs::Joy_<std::allocator<void> >]()->sensor_msgs::Joy_<std::allocator<void> >::axes.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[] [with _Tp = float, _Alloc = std::allocator<float>, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::const_reference = const float&, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = unsigned int](((unsigned int)((Servo*)this)->Servo::linear_))))’
```

I guess this means you can't use = with UInt16?

The second error is

```
/opt/ros/hydro/include/std_msgs/UInt16.h:55:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘double’ to ‘const std_msgs::UInt16_<std::allocator<void> >&’
```

This is also about UInt. I think my code is using UInt and float interchangeably. I don’t know how to get around this. I'm also unclear on how the Arduino node will read the Joy values. Is there a way to do the calculations with doubles and change them to UInt?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194049/joy-to-control-servo/) by [dshimano](https://answers.ros.org/users/19862/dshimano/) on ROS Answers with karma: 129 on 2014-10-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `std_msgs/UInt16` message is a wrapper around an integer type, not an integer type. This means that you can't assign directly into it; rather you have to set its `data` field. Try:

```
deg.data = l_scale_*joy->axes[linear_];
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-10-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dshimano](https://answers.ros.org/users/19862/dshimano/) on 2014-10-07**:
Thanks, that fixed it!